# mallformated URL from document referrer

Tags: javascript, url, flask, referrer

I am passing referrer URL from javascript to flask entry point function

but when I receive  on the flask side it looks like this `http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2F`

instead of `http:\\127.0.0.1:5000` how can I fix this ? should I fix it on the client end or on the flask end?

Comment: looks url encoded to me....

Comment: I tried `decodeURI( url)` as well as `decodeURIComponent(url)` but it doest work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - it`s just the URL with escaped special characters.

Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2F')
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
```

Python 2:

```
>>> from urllib import unquote
>>> unquote('http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2F')
'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
```

So, I think, you should just unquote it when using it on Flask end.

Also, take in account that there are 2 versions of unquote - `unquote()` and `unquote_plus()`. As the manual says: `unquote_plus()` is like `unquote()`, but 'also replaces plus signs by spaces, as required for unquoting HTML form values.'
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote

Comment: `ImportError: No module named parse`

Comment: It's Python 3 in my example. For Python 2 use:
`from urllib import unquote`

Comment: use what I think u missed it ?

Comment: Yes, I did :) Edited the comment now.

Comment: I`ve added little more info to the answer. You can check it, if you want. (Offtop: Do notifications about edits come to author of the question?)

Comment: @vchslv13 no they don't

Comment: @mangoHero1 Got it, thanks :)